# Count Time Spent across multiple view controllers ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS App that provides test for users with time limit.

The test will span across multiple view controllers, where these view controllers may re-open during the test flow. I think of the following flow:

In `AppDelegate.h`, add a `NSTimer` and time spent in `float`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic) float timeSpent;

- (void)startTimer;
- (void)stopTimer;
```

Without forgetting `@synthesize` the above, make a start & stop timer function in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)startTimer {
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1f target: self 
    selector: @selector(updateTime) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}
- (void)stopTimer {
  [self.timer invalidate];
}
```

In the periodically-called `updateTime` function, increment the value of `timeSpent` by 1.

Last, in each View Controller, obtain the `timeSpent` value and format it with the format I want, such as "01min 56s", or "01:56".

Is there a simpler way to do so?

Note:

- No Internet connection available, and the test will last for around 10 minutes only; thus using Google Analytics is an overkill & not applicable in this case

Comment: what you want to track a particular viewcontroller time or every viewcontroller?

Comment: track the time spent across multiple view controllers.

Comment: then did you track time in difference variable for different view controllers?

Comment: Only 1 timer (and 1 `timeSpent` variable`) will be used to track the time. Same variable

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you need one NSTimer and variable to track the global time and..
What you are proposing, using the app delegate as a glorified singleton will work..

But please don't, this is not very good practice. This blog post has a nice brief description on why, in my opinion at least.
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Personally if it was me I would probably just use a dependency injection model and pass the NSTimer between the viewControllers. http://www.objc.io/issue-15/dependency-injection.html

In short, app delegate is probably the easiest and quickest way. But I would advise something a little more scalable if it is going to be anything other than a trivial app.

Hope this was useful :)

*Edit Sample code for singleton.

This should go at the top of singleton class to initialise it.

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
@end

@implementation MySingletonClass

+ (instancetype)shared
{
    static MySingletonClass *_shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    _shared = [[self alloc] init];
    // any other initialisation you need
});
return _shared;
}

- (void)startTimer {
  self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1f target: self 
  selector: @selector(updateTime) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}
- (void)stopTimer {
  [self.myTimer invalidate];
}
```

then you can access it from any other classes in your program like this

```
#import "MySingletonClass.h"

//some method
- (void)myMethod
{
     CGFloat currentTime = [MySingletonClass shared].globalTimeProperty;
     // do something with the time
}

-(void)startTimer
{
     [[MySingletonClass shared] startTimer];
}

-(void)updateTime
{
    // do your update stuff here
}
```

Singleton header

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat globalTimeProperty;

+ (instancetype)shared;
- (void)startTimer;
- (void)stopTimer;

@end
```

I may have missed some stuff but it should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Um... please provide sample codes. Even short ones would be great.